# What low bias has to do with "good fit"

Tags: variance, bias, estimators

Look at the bias-variance decomposition below:

[image]

In pratice we often consider low bias as good fit to train data but i dont understand the why this by bias-variance decomposition.Why if i got "good fit" so i got low bias? The bias is evaluated by expectance measure not by train set MSE (for regression problem), would MSE worth as estimator for bias? if it would so low bias is a synonymous of good fit for regression problem.

Comment: In pratice we often consider low bias as good fit to train data but i dont understand the why this by bias-variance decomposition that is why low bias imples to good fit?

Comment: Look through again please i've tried to be clearer.

Comment: by good fit i mean low MSE on training data, why if MSE is low in training data so bias is low too? the only way that makes sense is if MSE is an estimator for bias.

Comment: It's pretty confusing i know the math is ok, but if i got low variance so i got low MSE ($Var(\hat{f}(x))\leq MSE(\hat{f}(x))$) then MSE near to 0 implies in low variance and bias but it can overfit but the overfitting is due to high variance it doenst make sense at all in anywhere. My guess is that variance of fit has nothing to do with model variance (if you mean $Var(X)$ as variance of fitted values) so sample bias-variance decomposition is pretty useless, the populational version deals to model's variance that is how much you model varies sample by sample.

Comment: You should denote $\hat{Var}(\hat{f}(x))$, i've meant MSE on training data not in population.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128006/discussion-between-davi-americo-and-galen).